# Generate VK_something dynamic for robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_something)

Tags: java

can I do something simliar to KeyCode.valueOf("G") with KeyEvent?
I want to press keys from the keyboard and I don´t want to write the same code to all the letters and combinations like this

```
            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_G);
            robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_G);
            robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);


            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_M);
            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0);
            robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0);
            robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_M);
```

I want to make something like:

```
 def press(arg1, arg2):
            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_arg1);
            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_arg2);
            robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_arg2);
            robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_arg1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    String sampleString = fooBar;
    int arg1 = sampleString.charAt(0);
    int arg2 = sampleString.charAt(1);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(arg1));
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(arg1));
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(arg2));
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(arg2));
```